# Sort soccer/football leaderboard table with direct matches

Tags: mysql, sql, sorting, leaderboard

I'm going crazy to get a sorted leaderbord for my project. I need a help because I have to sort the table by points, goal difference and direct matches. My problem is **direct matches**.
MySQL version: **5.7.29**

Here the tables structures and some example data:

```
CREATE TABLE `matches` (
  `id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `club_id_home` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `goals_home` tinyint(3) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `club_id_away` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `goals_away` tinyint(3) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `competition_id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
  `round` smallint(5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

INSERT INTO `matches` (`id`, `club_id_home`, `goals_home`, `club_id_away`, `goals_away`, `competition_id`, `round`) VALUES
(1, 1, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1),
(2, 3, 0, 4, 0, 1, 1),
(3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1),
(4, 4, 1, 2, 0, 1, 1);

CREATE TABLE `leaderboards` (
  `id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `club_id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `competition_id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
  `points` tinyint(3) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `wins` tinyint(3) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `losses` tinyint(3) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `draws` tinyint(3) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `goals_for` tinyint(3) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `goals_against` tinyint(3) UNSIGNED NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

INSERT INTO `leaderboards` (`id`, `club_id`, `competition_id`, `points`, `wins`, `losses`, `draws`, `goals_for`, `goals_against`) VALUES
(1, 1, 1, 4, 1, 1, 0, 4, 3),
(2, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 4),
(3, 3, 1, 2, 0, 2, 0, 1, 1),
(4, 4, 1, 4, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0);
```

So I have to check points (easy) and goal difference (easy) from leaderboards table, and direct matches from matches table so that if **Club A** and **Club B** have same points I have to check if Club A won or lost (or tied) against Club B.

So in my example I would like to see a leaderboard sorted like this:

```
club_id 4 | points: 4 | goals difference: 1
club_id 1 | points: 4 | goals difference: 1
club_id 3 | points: 2 | goals difference: 0
club_id 2 | points: 0 | goals difference: -2
```

Club 4 is first because it won the direct match against club 1.
How can I do it? Is it possible?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: *Here the tables structures* Post their CREATE TABLE, not DESCRIBE output which is unusable. Add some example data (as INSERT INTO) and desired result for this data with explanations. And specify MySQL version. *Is it possible?* Of course.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: I'm not that sporty but ism't a tie usually decided on goal difference as defined https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goal_difference

Comment: @P.Salmon the first criteria to resolve a points tie (in italian football Serie A) is "direct matches", goals difference is the second criteria. Teams play twice against each other, so that it is possible to tie also the direct matches.